# sql server 2012 developers edition license and 3rd party applications

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, license

Our company is using an ERP system for our product inventory management and customers orders. The newest version uses MS SQL 2012. if we are not developing software and the only users accessing the MS SQL 2012 database is the 3rd party application (ERP system) can we use the Developers Edition of SQL 2012?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because licensing questions are off-topic for this site, I'm afraid

Comment: I hope someone will be willing to answer my question as there are others in this site that are relevant to license issues. Thank you.

Comment: You are asking if you can use a developers license for a production application?

Comment: IMHO, any hybrid (i.e technical + business) questions with good intentions are justified here. In this case, license question is absolutely appropriate. I would even go further to say that questions or tips about how to minimize license cost, such as using a mix of SQL Express or Standard version to reduce total ownership cost should be more than welcome here and deserve some encouragements as well.

Answer (score 1):

No, the Developer Edition is for developers only. If it contains production data, you are not licensed and it doesn't matter that only the ERP system accesses the database, the users of your ERP system count as users of SQL server.